# Consecutive if statements: order of execution

Tags: python, if-statement

Here is my Python code:

```
my_constant = 5
my_constant_2 = 6
list_of_lists = [[3,2],[4,7]]

my_new_list = []

for i in list_of_lists:
    my_dict = {}
    for j in i:    
        if j > my_constant:
            my_dict["a"] = "Hello"
            my_dict["b"] = "Hello"
            print(my_dict)
            my_new_list.append(my_dict)
        if j > my_constant_2:
            my_dict["a"] = "Hello"
            my_dict["b"] = "Bye"
            print(my_dict)
            my_new_list.append(my_dict)


print(my_new_list)
```

Here are the results:

```
{'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'Hello'}
{'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'Bye'}
[{'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'Bye'}, {'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'Bye'}]
```

The first two lines of the results are according to my expectations, but the third line is not. I would expect this:

```
[{'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'Hello'}, {'a': 'Hello', 'b': 'Bye'}]
```

So it looks that when the loop waits for the second "if" before appending to my_new_list, and us such the my_new_list get twice the new my_dict.

I know that the below code solves the issue (ie moving the my_dict inside the "if"):

```
my_constant = 5
my_constant_2 = 6
list_of_lists = [[3,2],[4,7]]

my_new_list = []

for i in list_of_lists:
    for j in i:        
        if j > my_constant:
            my_dict = {}
            my_dict["a"] = "Hello"
            my_dict["b"] = "Hello"
            print(my_dict)
            my_new_list.append(my_dict)
        if j > my_constant_2:
            my_dict = {}
            my_dict["a"] = "Hello"
            my_dict["b"] = "Bye"
            print(my_dict)
            my_new_list.append(my_dict)


print(my_new_list)
```

However, in practice my_dict is not empty and a function is used to create it (and it takes some time). Also, there are more "ifs", so i prefer not to use the above code.

Is there a trick to get over it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are re-using same object again and again

use deepcopy:

```
from copy import deepcopy
my_constant = 5

my_constant_2 = 6
list_of_lists = [[3,2],[4,7]]

my_new_list = []

for i in list_of_lists:
    my_dict = {}
    for j in i:
        if j > my_constant:
            my_dict["a"] = "Hello"
            my_dict["b"] = "Hello"
            print(my_dict)
            my_new_list.append(deepcopy(my_dict))
        if j > my_constant_2:
            my_dict["a"] = "Hello"
            my_dict["b"] = "Bye"
            print(my_dict)
            my_new_list.append(my_dict)


print(my_new_list)
```

output:

```
{'b': 'Hello', 'a': 'Hello'}
{'b': 'Bye', 'a': 'Hello'}
[{'b': 'Hello', 'a': 'Hello'}, {'b': 'Bye', 'a': 'Hello'}]
```

Why deepcopy() why not copy ?

**Additional explanation :**

For understanding of deepcopy vs copy here is example code  :

> Let's explore your issue  by a little example:

so suppose you have a list:

```
a=['something']
```

And there is also a second list which contains:

```
list_1=[a,a,a]
```

So when you do:

```
a[0]="something_else"
```

what do you think what is the output of `list_1` ?

Let's check:

```
a=['something']
list_1=[a,a,a]


a[0]="something_else"
print(list_1)
```

output:

```
[['something_else'], ['something_else'], ['something_else']]
```

Because in python variable doesn't store the value , variable are just referece to the object and object store the value so in list_1 all the variable are pointing to the same object:

checking:

```
for i in list_1:
    print(id(i))
```

output:

```
4329477768
4329477768
4329477768
```

> Try deepcopy:
>
> why `deepcopy` why not `copy` ?

suppose you have dict like this:

```
dict_cell = {'item1': [20,34], 'item2': [25,9]}
```

you run your code with this dict_cell and you got the output:

```
[[{'item2': [25, 9], 'item1': 2}, {'item2': [25, 9], 'item1': [20, 34]}], [{'item2': [25, 9], 'item1': [20, 34]}, {'item2': [25, 9], 'item1': [20, 34]}]]
```

Now let's try to change the original dict values :

```
dict_cell = {'item1': [20,34], 'item2': [25,9]}
width = 2
height = 2
array = []
for i in range(height):
    row=[]
    for j in range(width):
        row.append(dict_cell.copy())
    array.append(row)
array[0][0]['item1'] =2


for key,value in dict_cell.items():
    value[0]='changed'

print(array,'\n')
```

output:

```
[[{'item1': 2, 'item2': ['changed', 9]}, {'item1': ['changed', 34], 'item2': ['changed', 9]}], [{'item1': ['changed', 34], 'item2': ['changed', 9]}, {'item1': ['changed', 34], 'item2': ['changed', 9]}]]
```

we modifed the orional dict but it changed the content in array list's dict because that is shallow copy of dict. it copied the dict but didn't copy the nested list.

> Solution :

Use deepcopy.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two versions of the code is that the first one appends the same dict to a list multiple times. The list will always contain the same dict repeated in this case.

However, nothing stops you from filling `my_dict` with pre-computed values:

```
defaults = {'some': 'common', 'values': 'here'}

for i in list_of_lists:
    for j in i:        
        if j > my_constant:
            my_dict = defaults.copy()
            my_dict["a"] = "Hello"
            my_dict["b"] = "Hello"
            print(my_dict)
            my_new_list.append(my_dict)
```

`defaults` can be calculated inside the loop if it depends on `i` or `j`.

If you are concerned with data duplication, just change the logic of your program and don't store repeating values in `my_new_list`.

Comment: So in my second code, when the my_dict = { } is inside the if blocks, does it mean that as i am initializing the my_dict again, the my_dict in the first if block is different from the my_dict in the second if block (and so the .copy() is done by default)?

Comment: @cmarios Yes, after you assign `my_dict` to a new (empty) dict, you don't affect the previously appended dict by changing `my_dict`. It refers to a different object now. When using `defaults`, you need to call `copy()` so that each time `my_dict` is a different object; otherwise they will all refer to `defaults` and again you'll see the same dict repeated.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_constant = 5
my_constant_2 = 6
list_of_lists = [[3,2],[4,7]]

my_new_list = []

for i in list_of_lists:
    my_dict = {}
    for j in i:    
        if j > my_constant:
            my_dict["a"] = "Hello"
            my_dict["b"] = "Hello"
            print(my_dict)
            my_new_list.append(my_dict.copy())
        if j > my_constant_2:
            my_dict["a"] = "Hello"
            my_dict["b"] = "Bye"
            print(my_dict)
            my_new_list.append(my_dict.copy())


print(my_new_list)
```

because in your code, my_new_list[0] and my_new_list[1] is same object.
So when you change the my_dict in if j > my_constant_2 block, then will be changed my_new_list[0] too.
please use copy or deepcopy when you add the object into my_new_list.
copy() function will do the shallow copy.
So it's good to use deepcopy for safety.

and I think my_dict initialization position is not proper.
please think about that.